# Error laravel 5.8 installing package (Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEKBg.png)

Using version ^8.0 for `laravel/passport`

> ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - laravel/passport 8.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support
[6.x-dev, 7.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1].
    - laravel/passport v8.0.0 requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[
6.x-dev, 7.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v5.8.35].
    - don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/support 7.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.35, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.35].
    - Installation request for laravel/passport ^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[8.x-dev, v8.0.0].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: Read your error messages. Laravel Passport 8.0 only works with Laravel 6.x. You either need to install an older version of passport or upgrade Laravel to version 6

Answer (score 3):

To install the most recent version [laravel/passport](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/passport) for **Laravel Framework 5.8**, run the following command

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

---

If you are still getting an error then install laravel/passport v7.5.1

Add to `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/passport": "^7.5.1"
    },
```

After, Run this command in the command prompt: `composer update`

I tested [laravel/passport v7.5.1](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/passport#v7.5.1) It is compatible with **Laravel Framework 5.8**

---

**NOTE:** If you need this version of **"laravel/passport": "^8.0"** then you must need [laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it obvious? To use the version of `laravel/passport ^ 8.0`.

You must install laravel 6.
Required statement: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade

What is the command you are using?

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

I recommend you use it. Laravel version you use will make the appropriate installation.

Answer (score 1):

use `composer require laravel/passport=^7.4`

Comment: Add an explanation so the user who asked understands the logic behind your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to include a previous version of passport, e.g.
`composer require laravel/passport "7.5.1"`

I would recommend Özgür Can Karagöz answer though if you have the time and your project isn't huge.

Answer (score 0):

> composer require laravel/passport "7.5.1"

is working for laravel version 5.8*